# Webform not allowed because it does not extend Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simple (currently) 1 page aspx website. It fails to compile with a message that I have not seen before. All other examples all seem to refer to master pages, which I do not have.

"Parser Error Message: 'Options.WebForm1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Options.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Here is the top of Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"     
Inherits="Options.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

And for Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace Options
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
```

Comment: `Inherits="Options.WebForm1"` shouldn't be `Inherits="Options._Default"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is Options.WebForm1 in <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Options.WebForm1" %>

It should look like this if you are using a namespace

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Options._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTest"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Id ="callfmptxt"/>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind-

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace Options
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        private double callfmp = 0;
        public double BlackScholes(string CallPutFlag, double S, double X, double T, double r, double v) { return 0.0;}
        protected void allfmptxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Varun, I wish I understood all this as well as you do. Perfect solution and thank you!

Comment: Your wish is gonna come true, don't worry.

Comment: Varun, thanks for the wish, but believe it or not, it worked for an hour, then failed again with the message "Could not load type 'Options._Default". I have no idea why!

Here is how the code looks

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"      
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Options._Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

Then in the .cs
    namespace Options
    {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {

Comment: Can you please share your code behind and the error you are getting now.

Comment: Thanks Varun for your quick reply. The error message is as I wrote it. Here is more of the code that follows, but I am out of space.

    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    namespace Options
    {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {
            private double callfmp = 0;
             ..
 
            public double BlackScholes(string CallPutFlag, double S, double   X,    double T, double r, double v)
            {
            ...
            }
            protected void callfmptxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
           }